# Using bootstrap timepicker/datepicker in visualforce

Tags: visualforce, javascript, bootstrap

I am trying to use a timepiker on an `apex:inputField` just like this figure

[image]

and here is my code
Visualforce

```
<apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.timepicker_js}"/> 
<apex:stylesheet value="{!$Resource.timepicker_css}"/> 

<apex:inputField value="{!object.Name}" styleClass="form-control input-md field_class"/>
```

JScript

```
$j(function () {
  $j('.field_class').datetimepicker({
    pickDate: false
  });
});
```

The problem is that I keep getting an error that `datetimepicker` is not defined.

Comment: Are you sure your Resource is loading correctly? Check your javascript console to see if you are getting an error. Could the timepicker_js be in a folder in your resource?

Comment: is your $j defined in the ready function?

Comment: @JimRae yes I'm sure, and I added an alert command to these files to be 100% sure that is loaded, and it's displayed.

Comment: @greenstork It's outside the ready function, but I tried to put inside it, the same result.

Comment: is your timepicker js loaded after jquery on the page and also with an includeScript tag?

Comment: can you paste your complete VF page, I have seen not defined errors due to 1) not having noconflict() 2) using multiple apex:includescript's

Comment: @greenstork I imported jQuery first, then bootstrap js files and css, then the timepicker files in a row.

Comment: @rao the whole page will be too much to paste here, do you think it would help ?

Comment: Not sure you have used nocoflict or not. make sure you are using compatible versions . also load your js and css through static resource. One more thing did you included moment js with your code

Answer (score 1):

Sounds crazy, but try including the source directly instead of using `<apex:includeScript>`. I've had similar issues with jQuery Mobile before now.

```
<!-- Change -->
<apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.timepicker_js}"/> 

<!-- To -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="{!$Resource.timepicker_Js}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used in below order with all component in a static resource.  Please try that

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/bower_components/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="/bower_components/moment/min/moment.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="/bower_components/eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker/build/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/bower_components/eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker/build/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.m

in.css" />
```

also, check [https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Installing/](http://here)

Answer (score -1):

I faced similar kind of error in bootstrap date-time picker for adding a time picker.
It seems you would also like to add a time-picker in the visualforce page.
I also added a timpicker in my visualforce page and no doubt it will work for sure.

You can take reference from my blog
[Timepicker](http://developforce.wordpress.com/2014/07/30/why-salesforce-do-not-have-a-time-field/)

Hope it would help you!!!

Comment: It can be better if you include relevant parts from your blog. From help page; "Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline."